# Can iOS apps share data?

Tags: ios

I am working on a set of apps which would likely use a lot of common data, by which I mean the same core data set of several hundred Mb.

It's analogous to if I had a set of downloadable maps, and several apps using it for different things.

Does iOS allow any way to share data between apps... I'd hope people would buy multiple apps as they are in the same area. Or is the right way to have one app and sell the functionality for each 'app' through in-app purchases?

Comment: Both things are not possible, you cannot share data directly between two iOS apps and also you cannot have one app and sell functionality for each app

Comment: What you can do is, create a single app and put all functionality into single app. Here you can make user for in app purchase for each functionality of your app to make enable.

Comment: I think that's what I meant - I _can_ activate specific modules of functionality in a single app by in-app payments? Do you know if any well-known 'big' apps do this (it's a high end expensive product for a small market)

Comment: There are many games, for example Subway Surf, if you want to buy coins, you go for in-app purchase multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can share data between apps in iOS , but , of course there are limitations to it.
Depends upon the amount of data and the data itself.

Ways In Which you can share Data:-

1 UIPasteBoard - 
Create a General Pasteboard With No Security

2 URL Scheme --
To register a URL type for your app, include the CFBundleURLTypes key in your app’s Info.plist file

Use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
  [NSURL URLWithString:@"yourApp://yourData"]];
```

to share data.

and to receive data ,the delegate for 4.1 and earlier

```
-application:handleOpenURL:
```

for later use :-

```
application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:
```

3 Dummy Contact For Sharing in AddressBook

4 You can even share data on Keychain but works only for iOS 3.xxxx.

Comment: I'm referring to downloaded data which apps need on the device, e.g. a big binary file of 100Mb. Not sure if your answers fit that without reading up on what you mention.

Comment: No It's not feasible to share data as large as that.

Comment: No It's not feasible to share data as large as that.You cannot use PasteBoards to share data as large as that . You may give a try to Custom URL Schemes please read the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520903/uipasteboard-size)..But , the user experience of the application won't be good.