# Is data handed over to UIPasteBoard deep copy or shallow copy?

Tags: ios, objective-c

If an app sets data in the UIPasteBoard of iOS, are they deep copied or shallow copied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIPasteboard uses NSData to store the data. Hence, it is deep copy.

From the official documentation for "setData:forPasteboardType:"

"Use this method to put raw data on the pasteboard. For example, you could **archive** a graph of model objects and pass the **resulting NSData object** to a related app via a pasteboard using a custom pasteboard type. (To put objects—such as NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSDate, NSNumber, UIImage, or NSURL objects—on the pasteboard, use the setValue:forPasteboardType: method.) This method writes data for the first item in the pasteboard. Calling this method replaces any items currently in the pasteboard."

Comment: I later found this out so had to post it for someone else to find out. I believe this is the proper answer though I accepted George's answer before.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask about `- (void)setData:(NSData *)data forPasteboardType:(NSString *)pasteboardType` than it is surely a Deep copy.

If you ask about `strings`, `URL's`, `Colors` they are also Deep copied.

Only about the `Images` I am preety sure that it uses the same `CGImageRef`, because UImage does not implement `NSCopying` protocol

You can test it just closing your application and see that data stays in the pasteboard.